# How to publish a docker image when you use spring-boot:build-image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, github-actions

I am using Github Actions to automate the process to push a docker image generated with the help of the maven plugin from Spring boot (mvn spring-boot:build-image), but I receive a maven error:

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution
> default-cli of goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.0:build-image
> failed: Error response received when pushing image: denied: requested
> access to the resource is denied

Using the following configuration:

```
  - name: Build image & push
    run: |
      cd myFolder
      mvn -X spring-boot:build-image \
        --batch-mode --no-transfer-progress \
        -Dspring-boot.build-image.publish=true \
        -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName="MY_USER/demo-ms:0.1.0" \
        -DCI_REGISTRY=https://index.docker.io/v1 \
        -DCI_REGISTRY_USER=${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }} \
        -DCI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.docker.auth

What I am missing?

Many thanks in advance

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 0):

In github actions, it is possible to run a Script, so I found an alternative:

At github action level:

```
  - name: Build image & push
    run: |
      cd myFolder
      ./build-spring-boot.sh ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }} ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}
```

At script level:

```
docker login "https://index.docker.io/v1/" -u="$1" -p="$2"

mvn spring-boot:build-image \
    --batch-mode --no-transfer-progress

IMAGE_NAME=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=docker.image.name -q -DforceStdout)
echo $IMAGE_NAME

docker push $IMAGE_NAME
```

In this way, you can publish your image.